# How do I install Komodo Edit?

Tags: installation

New to linux, help me install this program `Komodo-Edit-7.1.0-10496-linux-x86_64`

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Comment: What type of install is the program. .deb .tar.gz?

Comment: I highly recommend marking @LnxSlck's answer as correct. It's spot on.

Comment: that repo is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 15):

You could also use a repository, as described [here](http://handytutorial.com/install-komodo-edit-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10-using-ppa).

It includes Komodo Edit in Ubuntu in a much better way (accessible from the dash, some other Ubuntu conventions).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/komodo-edit
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install komodo-edit
```

---

To [complement the Ubuntu experience](http://community.activestate.com/node/9281), activate the Global Menu plugin.

Comment: If you encounter issues adding the repository when you are behind a proxy try `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/komodo-edit`

Comment: It works but get this message on connecting: "Update 2016-08-26:

Sorry, guys! No more updates here. I'm not using Komodo Edit anymore and today I am not able to build a new version of Komodo Edit. And I have no time to solve this. It has become too hard to support this PPA. 

Please, ask ActiveState to add support for Unity Menubar (https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/pull/868) and/or Ubuntu packages. It was nice to be with you these years. Thanks for your emails. It is the pleasure to know that my work is useful for people all over the world."

Comment: Yep, what @Peanut said. This seems to be not a good long-term solution any more we should not be upvoting it. We need another good answer.

Answer (score 7):

1. [Download the latest release.](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit)
2. `tar zxvf  Komodo-Edit-7.1.0-10496-linux-x86_64`
3. `cd  Komodo-Edit-7.1.0-10496-linux-x86_64`
4. `sudo ./install.sh`

When you are asked where you would like to install it go ahead and type the directory to where it should be installed.

Once it finishes you still have one more step, inserting the executable into your `PATH` variable. This can be done with a simple command:

5. `sudo ln -s "/home/myuser/Software/Komodo-Edit-7/bin/komodo" /usr/local/bin/komodo`

Answer (score 1):

Best Method of Installation is via Repository

Open Terminal and type the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/komodo-edit
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install komodo-edit
```

That's it ............it will get installed

for More details refer this link

http://dcageek.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-install-uninstall-komodo-edit-on.html

Comment: It seems that many of your answers are promoting your own blog site without mentioning that in your answers.

Comment: It works but get this message on connecting: "Update 2016-08-26: Sorry, guys! No more updates here. I'm not using Komodo Edit anymore and today I am not able to build a new version of Komodo Edit. And I have no time to solve this. It has become too hard to support this PPA. Please, ask ActiveState to add support for Unity Menubar (github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/pull/868) and/or Ubuntu packages. It was nice to be with you these years. Thanks for your emails. It is the pleasure to know that my work is useful for people all over the world."