# Linux newbie with Komodo edit installation issues

Tags: command-line, downloads, lamp, komodo-edit

I was watching a tutorial that needs komodo edit. I downloaded it but cant get the installer to run the way you just click the extraction file in windows. Any suggestions on what to do, maybe a solution from the terminal?

Comment: why do you want Komodo? You have Geany and Gedit, and they work without any issue. Unless there is something special I see no reason!

Comment: Installing on ubuntu is not the same as on windows, you rarely have to download files directly from websites. See the link above

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/172814/how-do-i-install-komodo-edit (mods, this is the correct duplicate, my mistake)

Answer (score 0):

U can try install it from repositores open a terminal type command i write u below and read instaruction on the screen :)  
<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
type 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/komodo-edit` 
 
then type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after finish updating type 
`sudo apt-get install komodo-edit`

if instalation is done u can run it from menu or type in terminal komodo-edit

Comment: Thanks everyone. Question was previously asked but answers didn't work. Now it does/did. I'm liking this community thing.